# Remote reset to Rasberry Pi without remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote, reset

I would know if there is a command to reset a Raspberry Pi without enter it with remote desktop (some like "reset 192.168.0.1 user=Pi pass=Password" or similar)

The problem is: I have a Raspberry Pi inside a network, and when I reset it, it runs automatically Chromium with a start page. If the start page is not running correctly, the user would reset it from his computer, but he don't know how to use the remote desktop, so I need to make a program/script in VBscript for the user, who can run it (from his desktop) and this program/scrtipt makes a reset in the Raspberry.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you prepared to use SSH?

Comment: The easiest way would be to do it via SSH. Putty can be run from the command line. You can script command line commands in VBScript. **OR** better yet, fix the start page that doesn't load correctly.

Comment: I think i'm prepared to use ssh, but I must verify it. I can't fix the page, so it's a webserver who runs the page. If the webserver is not started yet, the start page crashes....

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSH with password less login. This is a link to how to create password less login:

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-with-putty/

And from windows you could use putty and VBscript to do the work, inspiration can you find here:

https://www.onemanarmy.biz/vbscript-auto-login-ssh-connection-cisco-device-key-auth.php